# Codec for Serializer with Generic in Mongo Kotlin

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization, kotlinx, kmongo

I am trying to migrate from KMongo to the latest version of the Mongo Kotlin driver (4.11.0) using kotinx serialization and I am experiencing an issue with serializers and codecs.
I have this class with a generic parameter:

```
@Serializable(with = CharacterSerializer::class)
data class Character<P : Any> (
    @SerialName("_id") val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val player: P,
    val race: String?,
    val territory: String?,
    @SerialName("class") val characterClass: List<String> = emptyList(),
    val status: CharacterStatus = CharacterStatus.active,
    val masterMS: Int = 0,
    @SerialName("PBCMS") val pbcMS: Int = 0,
    val errataMS: Int = 0,
    val sessionMS: Int = 0,
    val errata: List<Errata> = emptyList(),
    @Contextual val created: Date? = null,
    @Contextual val lastPlayed: Date? = null,
    @Contextual val lastMastered: Date? = null,
    val age: Int? = null,
    val reputation: Map<String, Int>? = emptyMap(),
    val buildings: Map<String, List<Building>> = emptyMap(),
    val inventory: Map<String, Int> = emptyMap(),
    val languages: Set<ProficiencyStub> = emptySet(),
    val money: Float = 0f,
    val proficiencies: Set<ProficiencyStub> = emptySet(),
    val labels: Set<LabelStub> = emptySet()
)
```

and I also implemented a serializer with a generic parameter for it:

```
class CharacterSerializer<P : Any>(
    private val playerSerializer: KSerializer<P>
): KSerializer<Character<P>> {

    private val errataSerializer = Errata.serializer()
    private val proficiencyStubSerializer = ProficiencyStub.serializer()
    private val labelStubSerializer = LabelStub.serializer()
    private val characterStatusSerializer = CharacterStatusSerializer
    private val reputationSerializer = MapSerializer(String.serializer(), Int.serializer())
    private val buildingsSerializer = MapSerializer(String.serializer(), ListSerializer(Building.serializer()))
    private val inventorySerializer = MapSerializer(String.serializer(), Int.serializer())

    override val descriptor = buildClassSerialDescriptor("character") {
        element<String>("id")
        element<String>("name")
        element("player", playerSerializer.descriptor)
        element<String?>("race")
        element<String?>("territory")
        element<List<String>>("class")
        element<CharacterStatus>("status")
        element<Int>("masterMS")
        element<Int>("PBCMS")
        element<Int>("errataMS")
        element<Int>("sessionMS")
        element<List<Errata>>("errata")
        element("created", TimestampDateSerializer.descriptor)
        element("lastPlayed", TimestampDateSerializer.descriptor)
        element("lastMastered", TimestampDateSerializer.descriptor)
        element<Int?>("age")
        element<Map<String, Int>?>("reputation")
        element<Map<String, List<Building>>>("buildings")
        element<Map<String, Int>>("inventory")
        element<Set<ProficiencyStub>>("languages")
        element<Float>("money")
        element<Set<ProficiencyStub>>("proficiencies")
        element<Set<LabelStub>>("labels")
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Character<P>) {
        encoder.encodeStructure(descriptor) {
            encodeStringElement(descriptor, 0, value.id)
            encodeStringElement(descriptor, 1, value.name)
            encodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 2, playerSerializer, value.player)
            encodeNullableSerializableElement(descriptor, 3, String.serializer(), value.race)
            encodeNullableSerializableElement(descriptor, 4, String.serializer(), value.territory)
            encodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 5, ListSerializer(String.serializer()), value.characterClass)
            encodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 6, characterStatusSerializer, value.status)
            encodeIntElement(descriptor, 7, value.masterMS)
            encodeIntElement(descriptor, 8, value.pbcMS)
            encodeIntElement(descriptor, 9, value.errataMS)
            encodeIntElement(descriptor, 10, value.sessionMS)
            encodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 11, ListSerializer(errataSerializer), value.errata)
            encodeNullableSerializableElement(descriptor, 12, TimestampDateSerializer, value.created)
            encodeNullableSerializableElement(descriptor, 13, TimestampDateSerializer, value.lastPlayed)
            encodeNullableSerializableElement(descriptor, 14, TimestampDateSerializer, value.lastMastered)
            encodeNullableSerializableElement(descriptor, 15, Int.serializer(), value.age)
            encodeNullableSerializableElement(descriptor, 16, reputationSerializer, value.reputation)
            encodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 17, buildingsSerializer, value.buildings)
            encodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 18, inventorySerializer, value.inventory)
            encodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 19, SetSerializer(proficiencyStubSerializer), value.languages)
            encodeFloatElement(descriptor, 20, value.money)
            encodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 21, SetSerializer(proficiencyStubSerializer), value.proficiencies)
            encodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 22, SetSerializer(labelStubSerializer), value.labels)
        }
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Character<P> =
        decoder.decodeStructure(descriptor) {
            var id: String? = null
            var name: String? = null
            var player: P? = null
            var race: String? = null
            var territory: String? = null
            var classes: List<String>? = null
            var status: CharacterStatus? = null
            var masterMS: Int? = null
            var pbcMS: Int? = null
            var errataMS: Int? = null
            var sessionMS: Int? = null
            var errata: List<Errata>? = null
            var created: Date? = null
            var lastPlayed: Date? = null
            var lastMastered: Date? = null
            var age: Int? = null
            var reputation: Map<String, Int>? = null
            var buildings: Map<String, List<Building>>? = null
            var inventory: Map<String, Int>? = null
            var languages: Set<ProficiencyStub>? = null
            var money: Float? = null
            var proficiencies: Set<ProficiencyStub>? = null
            var labels: Set<LabelStub>? = null
            while (true) {
                when (val index = decodeElementIndex(descriptor)) {
                    0 -> id = decodeStringElement(descriptor, 0)
                    1 -> name = decodeStringElement(descriptor, 1)
                    2 -> player = decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 2, playerSerializer)
                    3 -> race = decodeNullableSerializableElement(descriptor, 3, String.serializer())
                    4 -> territory = decodeNullableSerializableElement(descriptor, 4, String.serializer())
                    5 -> classes =
                        try {
                            decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 5, ListSerializer(String.serializer()))
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            listOf(decodeStringElement(descriptor, 5))
                        }
                    6 -> status = decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 6, characterStatusSerializer)
                    7 -> masterMS = decodeIntElement(descriptor, 7)
                    8 -> pbcMS = decodeIntElement(descriptor, 8)
                    9 -> errataMS = decodeIntElement(descriptor, 9)
                    10 -> sessionMS = decodeIntElement(descriptor, 10)
                    11 -> errata = decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 11, ListSerializer(errataSerializer))
                    12 -> created = decodeNullableSerializableElement(descriptor, 12, TimestampDateSerializer)
                    13 -> lastPlayed = decodeNullableSerializableElement(descriptor, 13, TimestampDateSerializer)
                    14 -> lastMastered = decodeNullableSerializableElement(descriptor, 14, TimestampDateSerializer)
                    15 -> age = decodeNullableSerializableElement(descriptor, 15, Int.serializer())
                    16 -> reputation = decodeNullableSerializableElement(descriptor, 16, reputationSerializer)
                    17 -> buildings = decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 17, buildingsSerializer)
                    18 -> inventory = decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 18, inventorySerializer)
                    19 -> languages = decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 19, SetSerializer(proficiencyStubSerializer))
                    20 -> money = decodeFloatElement(descriptor, 20)
                    21 -> proficiencies = decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 21, SetSerializer(proficiencyStubSerializer))
                    22 -> labels = decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 22, SetSerializer(labelStubSerializer))
                    CompositeDecoder.DECODE_DONE -> break
                    else -> error("Unexpected index: $index")
                }
            }
            Character(
                id = requireNotNull(id) { "Character id cannot be null" },
                name = requireNotNull(name) { "Character name cannot be null" },
                player = requireNotNull(player) { "Character player cannot be null" },
                race = race,
                territory = territory,
                characterClass = requireNotNull(classes) { "Character classes cannot be null" },
                status = requireNotNull(status) { "Character status cannot be null" },
                masterMS = requireNotNull(masterMS) { "Character masterMS cannot be null" },
                pbcMS = requireNotNull(pbcMS) { "Character pbcMS cannot be null" },
                errataMS = requireNotNull(errataMS) { "Character errataMS cannot be null" },
                sessionMS = requireNotNull(sessionMS) { "Character sessionMS cannot be null" },
                errata = requireNotNull(errata) { "Character errata cannot be null" },
                created = created,
                lastPlayed = lastPlayed,
                lastMastered = lastMastered,
                age = age,
                reputation = reputation,
                buildings = requireNotNull(buildings) { "Character buildings cannot be null" },
                inventory = requireNotNull(inventory) { "Character inventory cannot be null" },
                languages = requireNotNull(languages) { "Character languages cannot be null" },
                money = requireNotNull(money) { "Character money cannot be null" },
                proficiencies = requireNotNull(proficiencies) { "Character proficiencies cannot be null" },
                labels = requireNotNull(labels) { "Character labels cannot be null" },
            )
        }
    
}
```

Now, when I try to use a simple find on the collection, I get this error:

```
Could not find codec for player with type Porg.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Could not find codec for player with type P
```

So, following the documentation, I tried to register a codec and add it to the database. However, I cannot manage to do so. If I try:

```
        val characterCodec = KotlinSerializerCodec.create<Character<Any>>(
            serializersModule = SerializersModule {
                contextual(Date::class, TimestampDateSerializer)
                polymorphic(Any::class) {
                    subclass(Character.serializer(PolymorphicSerializer(Any::class)))
                }
            }
        )
```

However, this returns null. I also tried to erase the type on the method with no avail.

```
        val characterCodec = KotlinSerializerCodec.create<Character<*>>(
            serializersModule = SerializersModule {
                contextual(Date::class, TimestampDateSerializer)
                polymorphic(Any::class) {
                    subclass(Character.serializer(PolymorphicSerializer(Any::class)))
                }
            }
        )
```

Them I tried to specify the serializer explicitly:

```
        val characterCodec = KotlinSerializerCodec.create(
                kClass = Character::class,
                serializer = Character.serializer(PolymorphicSerializer(Any::class)),
                bsonConfiguration = BsonConfiguration(encodeDefaults = false),
                serializersModule = SerializersModule {
                    contextual(Date::class, TimestampDateSerializer)
                    polymorphic(Any::class) {
                        subclass(Character.serializer(PolymorphicSerializer(Any::class)))
                    }
                }
            )
```

However, this does not compile.
Does someone know how to solve this problem?